# ASP.NET MVC OutputCache doesn't work for root URI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, action, outputcache

I'm learning ASP.NET MVC and bugged by one issue.

In the HomeController, the Index action has OutputCache attribute, but it seems doesn't work.

```
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [OutputCache(Duration=5, VaryByParam="none")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page" + DateTime.Now;
        ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC! " + DateTime.Now;

        return View();
    }
}
```

After quite a few minutes trying, I found that it is due to the way I access the action. If I access it through "http://localhost:3573/", the outputcache doesn't work. However, if I access it with "http://localhost:3575/Home/Index", the outputcache works.

Anybody know any workaround to make the default controller-action outputcacheable?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem here.

Comment: any of you people using chrome? i've noticed some wierdness in chrome caching

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is a bug in ASP.NET MVC. We have logged the issue in our database and will investigate a fix for this issue.

Thanks,
Eilon

Comment: Will you also fix the bug where setting VaryByParam to "None" will emit the HTTP response header "Vary: *", which is the opposite of what should happen?

Comment: @Eilon I'm still seeing this still as an issue, have you any recommendations for caching a root uri? other than redirecting to /home ;)

Answer (score 1):

using VarByParam="" seems to make it work

Answer (score 1):

According to my contacts at Microsoft, the issue disappears entirely if you remove the Default.aspx file from the root of your site, or, if you absolutely need to have it, make sure you use the one that's provided with the latest version of ASP.NET MVC.