# OutputCache Bug with VaryByParam="None" with MVC RC refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outputcache

Came across to [this defect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323458/asp-net-mvc-outputcache-doesnt-work-for-root-uri/325093) with ASP.NET RC refresh while using `VaryByParam=""` instead of `VaryByParam="None"`.

Caching WORKS, but page http://www.yoursite.com and http://www.yoursite.com/home/index will be cached separately it seems.

What is the difference between `VaryByParam=""` and `VaryByParam="None"`?

edit : I mean `VaryByParam=""` not VaryByParam="*" cause the bug still exists with VaryByParam="*"

Answer (score 5):

VaryByParam="*" will create a new cache for every different parameter passed.
VaryByParam="None" will create one and only one cache, regardless of parameters.

Comment: I meant VaryByParam="" not VaryByParam="*" cause  the bug still exists with VaryByParam="*"

Comment: Instead of using VaryByParam="None" I suggest to use VaryByParam="" (empty string). Otherwise the cache will create a new entry if the user specify the `None` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Route elements are not considered parameters for OutputCache.

[What is VaryByParam in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899728/what-is-varybyparam-in-asp-net)