# What is VaryByParam in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

While I am working on cache, there is something like

> VaryByParam

in page directive. So what is this? Can anybody explain it to me?

Comment: You can find an detailed explanation in the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538012/how-do-i-use-varybyparam-with-multiple-parameters

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From [@ OutputCache (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy.aspx):

> A semicolon-separated list of strings used to vary the output cache. By default, these strings correspond to a query string value sent with GET method attributes, or a parameter sent using the POST method. When this attribute is set to multiple parameters, the output cache contains a different version of the requested document for each specified parameter. Possible values include none, *, and any valid query string or POST parameter name.

By using it, if you call your page using same variable value, that page will be retrieved from your cache and will not be executed until time especified in `Duration` argument be reached.

Comment: Mr. Rubbens Faria if i want to place the cache only for one web control like Label how can i write

Comment: You can write a user control (.ASCX) which contains your label and to add that `@OutputCache` into that control. Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h30h475z.aspx

Comment: Ok ok i understood Thank Mr. Rubens Farias

Answer (score 43):

To quote from the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy.aspx):

> A semicolon-separated list of strings used to vary the output cache. By default, these strings correspond to a query string value sent with GET method attributes, or a parameter sent using the POST method. When this attribute is set to multiple parameters, the output cache contains a different version of the requested document for each combination of specified parameters. Possible values include none, an asterisk (*), and any valid query string or POST parameter name.

So, if you set it to `"A;B"`, then these URLs will be cached separately:

```
http://example.com/yourpage.aspx?A=1&B=4
http://example.com/yourpage.aspx?A=1&B=3
http://example.com/yourpage.aspx?A=2&B=3
```

but those URLs will access the same cache entry:

```
http://example.com/yourpage.aspx?A=1&C=4
http://example.com/yourpage.aspx?A=1&C=3
```

Comment: This is actually a slightly better answer than the accepted one because of the examples.