# How do I use VaryByParam with multiple parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, outputcache

In ASP.NET MVC2 I use `OutputCache` and the `VaryByParam` attribute. I got it working fine with a single parameter, but what is the correct syntax when I have several parameters on the method?

```cs
[OutputCache(Duration=30, VaryByParam = "customerId"]
public ActionResult Index(int customerId)
{
//I've got this one under control, since it only has one parameter
}

[OutputCache(Duration=30, VaryByParam = "customerId"]
public ActionResult Index(int customerId, int languageId)
{
//What is the correct syntax for VaryByParam now that I have a second parameter?
}
```

How do I get it to cache the pages using both parameters? Do I enter add the attribute twice? Or write "customerId, languageId" as the value??

Answer (score 216, accepted):

Valid values for `VaryByParam` are one of the following:

- The literal string `*` (asterisk), which varies by *all* parameters of the action method.
- The literal string `none` (case-insensitive), which varies by *no* parameters of the action method.
- A string containing the semicolon-separated names of the parameters you wish to vary by.

In your case, you'd want the first option:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 30, VaryByParam = "*")]
public ActionResult Index(int customerId, int languageId)
{
}
```

If, however, you had some params you want to vary by and some that you don't, then you'd use the third option:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 30, VaryByParam = "customerId;languageId")] // foo is omitted
public ActionResult Index(int customerId, int languageId, int foo)
{
}
```

[Reference.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs#varying-the-output-cache)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `*` to include all parameters

```
 [OutputCache(Duration =9234556,VaryByParam = "*")]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)