# @OutputCache with varyByparam and Url routing in ASP.NET 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, caching, url-routing, outputcache

i am trying to implement cache by varyByparam with url routing.

i have url as

```
routes.MapPageRoute("ProductByDate", "Product/sold/{date}", "~/CommonPages/ProductByDate.aspx");
```

Now varyByparam="date" but it doesn't seem to work. Can somebody guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Route elements are not considered parameters by OutputCache.

[What is VaryByParam in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899728/what-is-varybyparam-in-asp-net)

cheers.